# Solana error on metaplex when trying to make auction

Tags: rust, solana, metaplex

So I’m working on a metaplex project and when I try to launch an auction I’m getting a few errors and when I look for answers I’m not finding anything that makes much sense to me.

Also search the rust documents and didn’t have luck.

But one error is

#1 Metaplex NFT Auction instruction

> Program log: + Processing CreateAuction
> Program log: Transfer 141190560 lamports to the new account
> Invoking System Program
> Program returned success
> Program log: Allocate space for the account
> Invoking System Program
> Program returned success
> Account data size realloc limited to 10240 in inner instructions
> Program Metaplex NFT Auction  consumed 9991 of 200000 compute units
> Program returned error: Failed to reallocate account data

Another is

#1 System Program instruction

> Program returned success
> #2 Token Program instruction
> Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount
> Program Token Program  consumed 3295 of 200000 compute units
> Program returned success
> #3 Metaplex Program instruction
> Program log: Instruction: Init Auction Manager V2
> Program log: This safety deposit box is not listed as a prize in this auction manager!
> Program Metaplex Program  consumed 5430 of 200000 compute units
> Program returned error: custom program error: 0x1b

Another is

Raw
#1 System Program instruction

> Program returned success
> #2 Token Program instruction
> Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount
> Program Token Program  consumed 3295 of 200000 compute units
> Program returned success
> #3 Metaplex Program instruction
> Program log: Instruction: Init Auction Manager V2
> Program log: This safety deposit box is not listed as a prize in this auction manager!
> Program Metaplex Program  consumed 5430 of 200000 compute units
> Program returned error: custom program error: 0x1b

Another is

Raw
#1 System Program instruction

> Program returned success
> #2 Token Program instruction
> Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount
> Program Token Program  consumed 3295 of 200000 compute units
> Program returned success
> #3 Metaplex Program instruction
> Program log: Instruction: Init Auction Manager V2
> Program log: This safety deposit box is not listed as a prize in this auction manager!
> Program Metaplex Program  consumed 5430 of 200000 compute units
> Program returned error: custom program error: 0x1b

Another is

#1 Metaplex NFT Auction instruction

> Program log: + Processing CreateAuction
> Program log: Transfer 141190560 lamports to the new account
> Invoking System Program
> Program returned success
> Program log: Allocate space for the account
> Invoking System Program
> Program returned success
> Account data size realloc limited to 10240 in inner instructions
> Program Metaplex NFT Auction  consumed 9991 of 200000 compute units
> Program returned error: Failed to reallocate account data

Another is

#1 System Program instruction

> Program returned success
> #2 Token Program instruction
> Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount
> Program Token Program  consumed 3295 of 200000 compute units
> Program returned success
> #3 Metaplex Program instruction
> Program log: Instruction: Init Auction Manager V2
> Program log: This safety deposit box is not listed as a prize in this auction manager!
> Program Metaplex Program  consumed 5430 of 200000 compute units
> Program returned error: custom program error: 0x1b

You can see my solscan info too below

Appreciate your help and thank you in advance

https://solscan.io/account/6US2oFFpyidDHTGh1rbBm1AvbHU8ex2aRk1rNsZNqNRj

Comment: You are supposed to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and a lot more details about your code and the errors you get, otherwise it's impossible to help you...

Comment: I don’t know what code I would be posting here. The metaplex store is up and running and I can only see the errors I posted from solscan?

Comment: Well, a good start would be posting any code at all. Imagine I asked you "help me I get a syntax error when I try to compile my code", and that's it. You couldn't help me no matter how hard you try.

Comment: I posted the errors I was getting. I thought  those would be of help since I don’t know what they mean and was trying to understand what they were